# How do I write angular-ui-router code to ensure maximum compatibilty to new angular router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-new-router

For a large application I have to re-design the navigation and routing concept.
As far as I see, the new angular router, which was announced for 1.4 (and 2.0) is still not production ready. All the information I found about the new router sounds very primising, but seems to be outdated, at least regarding the API. I'm not sure, if I should use a library in such an early state, without documentation.

Therefore I think, currently we better should use ui-router.

Can I use the angular ui-router in a way that would allow an easy replacement in future?

Should I work with named and nested views? Can I use states in my templates or should I better link to the url? Should I use abstract states? Which of the ui-router options / patterns I should avoid because they are complete incompatible with the components concept ot new router?

Comment: I'm trough the same scenario and looking for the best way to replace it under your same arguments.

Comment: There is no documentation, again.... Would also like to know that. Maybe one of the angular devs is around here?